# Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.Xna, Xna does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, xna

I have created a Mobile application, and as it's my first application, and I'm learning how to do windows phone applications, I want to insert ads into.

I have seen this site: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8adb6cb5-4274-40b3-b1eb-4f06fdaedb86/how-do-i-add-advertisements-in-my-app?forum=wpdevelop

but when I add `using Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.Xna` I have been able to add the reference `Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile` and `Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI` but I haven't found `Microsoft.Avertising.Mobile.Xna`

Is there an other way to insert ads created by Microsoft PubCenter, Am I missing something about `Xna`?

Comment: From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524179(v=msads.20).aspx) ... Assembly: Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.Xna (in Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.Xna.dll) Version: 6.1.909.0- Have you included this?

Comment: If to add the .dll I have to use NuGet, I have tried, but didn't found.

Comment: You just include a reference to the dll, NuGet doesn't come into it

Comment: When look for references to add, I find `Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile` and `Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI` but I don't find `Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.Xna` I'm using VS express 2012 for windows phone, could it be the reason why I don't find the reference in the Reference Manager?

Comment: I've never used this dll before .. do you have it on your local machine?

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe I could find it on internet? But... Xna is for game applications... My application isn't a game one, maybe it's the reason why I don't find id and I must use `Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should follow these steps for windows phone 7 Advertising Sdk Implementation:

1. Installing the Microsoft Advertising SDK.
2. Registering the application with the Microsoft pubCenter.
3. Embedding the ad control in the application.

For Implementing AdControl in App you can try this:

XAML:

```
<advertising:AdControl ApplicationId="test_client"
                               AdUnitId="Image480_80">
                               </advertising:AdControl>
```

Note: Add this in `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>` Tag

```
xmlns:advertising="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;assembly=Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI"
```

After this you can see Test Ads in your Application.

for more Reference you can go here [Using display ads in Windows Phone 7 apps](http://joshearl.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/using-display-ads-in-windows-phone-7-apps/)  and you can find good sample here [Windows Phone 7 AdControl Example](http://joshearl.codeplex.com/releases/view/64631)

Comment: Okay thank you. I'll try and accept your answer soon, souds be precisely what I was looking for! Just in order to sleep less ignorant tonight, Xna is only for Games application, is it the reason why I haven't found it on my application?

Comment: Is it normal I don't see the ads in the windows phone emulator? Or have I missed something? I've got this: `<advertising:AdControl BorderBrush="White" Grid.Row="14" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Column="0" ApplicationId="***********************"
                               AdUnitId="******">
                    </advertising:AdControl>`

Comment: we can not see ads in emulator. for getting ads we need to deploy it to real device